# Tuple index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

We've been working on this function that is supposed to compute the final grades for some students, based on their grades in a number of assignments. Our input is a NxM matrix containing grades for N students and M assignments (and a grade is a number). The function is supposed to do the following 3 things:

1. If there is only one assignment ( M = 1), the final grade must be the same as the grade for that assignment.
2. if there are two assignments or more, the lowest grade is discarded and the final grade is calculated as the mean of M-1.
3. if the student receives the grade -3, the final grade must also be -3.

We've been trying out the following code (`roundGrades()` is another function we have created), but we keep on getting errors.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

```py
def computeFinalGrades(grades):
    grades = np.array(grades)
    SortData = np.sort(grades)
    gradesFinal = np.zeros(np.size(grades, axis = 0))

    for i in range(np.size(grades, axis = 0)):        
        if np.size(grades, axis = 1) == 1:
            gradesFinal[i] = grades[i,0]

        elif np.any(grades[i] == -3):
            gradesFinal[i] = -3

        else:
            gradesFinal[i] = roundGrade([np.mean(SortData[i,1::])])[0]

    return gradesFinal
```

The error message we get right now is:

```py
if np.size(grades, axis = 1) == 1:
File "C:\Users\h\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2931, in size
    return a.shape[axis]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But the program has also previously complained about the line that uses `np.sort()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code defines a function and terminates without calling it.  Also, you allude to multiple errors, but supply no evidence.

Comment: @HL you will need to supply sample input (what is the content of the variable `grades`) so we can try to reproduce the error and help you further.

Comment: @HL and please NEVER EVER cut the error traceback short. In its current form we cannot see in which line caused the error, so it would help if you add the full error traceback.

Comment: @Ralf It appears to say that the error happens on the line `if np.size(grades, axis = 1) == 1:`, so the problem happens when calling `np.size()`

Comment: Which I think means that the `grades` array is 1-dimensional, but you're expecting it to be 2-dimensional.

Comment: @Ralf the data is a .csv file that contains the following information: ID number, Name, Assignment 1, Assignment 2, Assignment 3. An example could be: s18739, Jim Peterson, 7, 12, 4

Comment: You don't show how you load the `csv`, but with data like that I imagine `grades` is a structured array (or possibly dataframe).  The error indicates that it is not a (N,M) matrix.  More likely it is (N,) shape with M fields.